# Logo Tab ?? needed for embedded signing application

Tags: docusignapi

I have a standard credit check authorization for borrowers will need to sign for the 100+ banks that will use our solution. I push Bank Name, Borrower name, SSN, etc into the document using the different tabs.

What I would also like to do is put in the bank's logo on the upper left corner of the document.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Branding capability](https://support.docusign.com/guides/cdse-admin-guide-branding) to change the entire look and feel of the app, including the bank's logo, colors, etc.

You could also use a different template document for each bank. The document would include the bank's logo.